# How to find the similarity transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, similar-matrices

Here's the question I got stuck on:

> Suppose $S$ is a matrix that performs a similarity transformation.
> Applying $S$ to the point $(0, 0)$ takes it to the point $(3, 2)$. Applying $S$ to the point $(1, 2)$ takes it to the point $(2, 5)$. What is $S$?

My intuition was using the formula: $A = P^{-1}BP$ to approach this question.

The definition of the formula is that let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. If we can find a non-singular $n \times n$ matrix $P$ as the formula shows, then $A$ and $B$ are similar to each other.

I just started learning linear algebra, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $S^{-1} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} 
S
$ makes no sense. The sizes don’t match.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of trick question. Assuming that there are no typos in the given vectors, there is no such linear transformation $S$. Here's why:

Notice how
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 2 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 2 \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
so if
$$
S \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 2 
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
then by linearity,
$$
S \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 2 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 2 S \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 2 \begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 2 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
8 \\ 4 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
But, we are *also* given that
$$
S \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 2 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\ 5 
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
a contradiction! Therefore, no such linear transformation $S$ exists.

Comment: Note that this is similarity transformation, so probably such linear transformation exists?